# jQuery input:radio change val text in help-block

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form where if the value is one thing, the text that appears in the .help-block should change accordingly. Here is the form: http://lakenney.github.io/contact.html  Check the box for 'I'd like something custom made' and the radio buttons drop down. Click on the first Swarovski necklace radio button and the corresponding text 'Swarovski crystals sparkle' appears in the .help-block. But the other radio buttons don't work.

I have an example that works with the selection element: http://lakenney.github.io/form-start-video2.html ... see "Please select one" and the corresponding text populates the .help-block

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your javascript to this instead:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == 'swarovski') {
            $('.request-custom .help-block').text('Swarovski crystals sparkle');
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'mirano') {
            $('.request-custom .help-block').text('Mirano crystals sparkle');
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'locket') {
            $('.request-custom .help-block').text('Lockets are awesome!');
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'soldering') {
            $('.request-custom .help-block').text('Soldering Rock!');
        } else {
            $('.request-custom .help-block').text('');
        }

});
```

Basically, use

> $(this).val()

to capture the value. You are currently using

> $('input:radio').val()

which will result always in returning the FIRST $('input:radio'), which happens to be swarovski.